# how to retrofit and room handle nested object

Tags: android-room

```
 "provinsi": [
        {
            "createdDate": 1490089930310,
            "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
            "updatedDate": 1490089930310,
            "updatedBy": "SYSTEM",
            "id": 31,
            "provinceName": "Kepulauan Riau",
            "provinceCode": "0",
            "mCities": [
                {
                    "createdDate": 1490092020000,
                    "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
                    "updatedDate": 1490092020000,
                    "updatedBy": "SYSTEM",
                    "provinceName": "Kepulauan Riau",
                    "id": 198,
                    "cityName": "KAB.BINTAN",
                    "cityCode": "2102",
                    "centralBankCode": ""
                },
                {
                    "createdDate": 1490092020000,
                    "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
                    "updatedDate": 1490092020000,
                    "updatedBy": "SYSTEM",
                    "provinceName": "Kepulauan Riau",
                    "id": 350,
                    "cityName": "KAB.KARIMUN",
                    "cityCode": "2101",
                    "centralBankCode": "3801"
                },

}
]
```

I tried to make it a relation table, or two tables. find good documentation for this but it's hard hahaha but can't find something like this

Comment: I tried to make it a relation table, or two tables. find good documentation for this but it's hard hahaha but can't find something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be a `one-to-many` relation. For example

Entity

```java
@Entity
data class Dog(
    @PrimaryKey val dogId: Long,
    val dogOwnerId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val cuteness: Int,
    val barkVolume: Int,
    val breed: String
)

@Entity
data class Owner(@PrimaryKey val ownerId: Long, val name: String)

data class OwnerWithDogs(
    val owner: Owner,
    val dogs: List<Dog>
)

data class OwnerWithDogs(
     @Embedded val owner: Owner,
     @Relation(
          parentColumn = "ownerId",
          entityColumn = "dogOwnerId"
     )
     val dogs: List<Dog>
)
```

Dao

```java
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Owner")
fun getDogsAndOwners(): List<OwnerWithDogs>
```

You can see a good article at [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542).

I hope this will be helpful.